# Does wagtail early versions support GCP Datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, wagtail

Now we have our project up and running on google-app-engine using cloud SQL as the back-end database system but the client somehow wants to convert to Datastore so what are the opportunities to use Datastore with Wagtail 1.13 or greater without having any troubles.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://pypi.org/project/wagtail/2.1/#compatibility, the only databases officially supported by current versions of Wagtail (as of 2.1) are PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLite.

GCP Datastore and other NoSQL databases are unsupported. There's a remote possibility that it could be made to work with a suitable backend such as [Djangae](https://potatolondon.github.io/djangae/), but you would be responsible for fixing any bugs that arise.